# How I can redirect to page in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, header, login-script

I try to make a login form for my active page. The registration also completed. My problem is, that when I was get that I logged in successfully, I cannot to redirect to startpage with 'header(location:)'. Please help me, or fix the php's errors. Thanks!

Note: the links of the php are samples, aren't real.

```
<?php

$hostname="host"; // Host of MySQL
$user="user"; // Username at MySQL
$password="pass"; // Password at MySQL
$dbname="db"; // Database on MySQL

$connection=mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $password);
    if(! $connection)
        {
            die(''.mysqlerror());
        }
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die('');

$given_email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$given_pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$given_email' and password='$given_pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{    
    //echo "OK";
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
    //setUrl ("http://testseite.aufderlicht.bplaced.de/loggedin/start.html");
}
    else 
    {
        setUrl ("http://testseite.aufderlicht.bplaced.de/login/err/err.html");
    }

//mysql_close($connection)

?>
```

Comment: What arror are you getting instead of a redirect?

Comment: make sure there is no output before the header call, that will give error

Comment: Maybe your spaces are playing tricks on you. Try `header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html');` without spaces after `header(` etc.

Comment: make the path relative instead of including the full path.  i.e. /loggedin/start.html and /login/err/err.html

Comment: Also, if there is space before the php tag in your script then `header()` won't work. Plus, add `exit()` or `die()` after the `header()` to avoid any problems and stop execution of script.

Comment: @developerwjk - Actually, HTTP formally requires absolute URLs for redirects. It normally works with relatives, but it's better to use absolutes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just put the '/' relative path in the header:

```
header ('Location: /');
```

However, this is the recommended:

```
header ('Location: http://example.com/');
```

Doing only this won't work: <strike>`header ('Location: ');`</strike>, as can be seen in the specifications:

> Note:
>    HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

Also, few notes:

- **[Do NOT store passwords in plain text](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/)**. Even thought this note won't fix your code, it's very important.
- Include some error inside every `die('')`. As they stand, they only kill the script without providing any useful information. It could perfectly be that one of them is being triggered. For example:

`mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die('Could not select database');`

- Don't use mysql_* functions for new code since they are deprecated, PDO or mysqli_* are much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirection using Javascript instead of PHP page,especially because some webhosts don't allow using header() in the middle of files.

here is an example :

```
       echo "
         <script type='text/javascript'>
              window.location.replace('http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html');

         </script>";
```